# select rows where row below may have same data

Tags: ms-access

I have this:

```
row  name       company         cusaddr_1
1    Bob        Happy Valley    1 RIVER PARKWAY
2               Happy Valley    1 RIVER PARKWAY
3    Lorie      Pet supply      1 Falls Rd
4    Greg       Pet supply      1 Falls Rd
5               Pet supply      1 Falls Rd
6               A Best Auto     1 camp dr
7    Ron        1 Broadway Ave
```

what I want is to return rows 1,3,4,6,7. Basically, how can I select rows where the company has a name and is a duplicate but still keep the rows like row 6 where there is only one option of company and no name? This is Access 2013 and I created the table doing a union query like this:

```
select DISTINCT blName as name, company, cusaddr_1
from one_table
union all
select DISTINCT shName as name, company, cusaddr_1
from one_table
```

Comment: As for your example, what should happen if row 2 did contain the name Bob?

Comment: Then I would only want to see one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a query with a WHERE clause checking whether rows with a blank name for the company have another record with a name in it, and excluding the record if it does:

```
WHERE (name is NOT NULL) or 
((name IS NULL) AND (company IN 
   (SELECT company FROM one_table GROUP BY company HAVING MAX(name) IS NULL)))
```

If you need to only return one row for companies that have only blank names then I would create the WHERE clause against the row number:

```
WHERE (name is NOT NULL) or 
((name IS NULL) AND (row In 
(SELECT Min(row) FROM one_table GROUP BY company HAVING MAX(name) Is Null)))
```

Comment: My list is built from a union query where 'name' is built from the unions (see the sql after the list) How could I use your idea with 'name' being created from the union query?

Comment: You could use a make table query from the union query and then put the WHERE clause in a query against that table.  If you don't want to do this you can substitute the UNION query in the table name like so:  SELECT * FROM ([union query here]) TABLE1 WHERE ...you'd have to do the same substitution for one_table in the subquery as well.